# Can't access sub array fields in $map

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an object like so

```
{
      "_id": "62334a3c86f03ce0985f11a1",
      "stops": [
        {
          "location": {
            "baseLocation": "622e29bd0a56c69f81e0e6e9",
            "extraLocation": "622e29bd0a56c69f81e0e6eb"
          },
          "timesData": [
            {
              "wType": "date"
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          "location": {
            "baseLocation": "622e70a59975be022276178c",
            "extraLocation": "622e70a59975be022276178e"
          },
          "timesData": [
            {
              "wType": "date"
            }
          ],
          }
        },
      ],
    }
```

I need to find the index of objects that have a `baseLocation` equal to a value and which have a `wType` of `date` and I do so using a `$map` like the one below

```
  {
    $map: {
      input: "$stops",
      in: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: ["$$this.location.baseLocation", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(from.id)]
          },
          {
            $eq: ["$$this.timesData.0.wType", "date"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

I get no matches, but if I do it like this

```
  {
    $map: {
      input: "$stops",
      in: {
            $eq: ["$$this.location.baseLocation", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(from.id)]
      }
    }
  },
```

It works, so I guess the problem is that I can't access `"$$this.timesData.0.wType"`

Answer (score 0):

How about using $arrayElemAt:

```
    $map: {
      input: "$stops",
      in: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.location.baseLocation",
              mongoose.Types.ObjectId(from.id)]
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$this.timesData",
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                "wType": "date"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can check it on the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/p5eRv0pXYXM